# alarm sound in android application

Tags: android

I want to know that how to set my own sound in setting alarm in android

Comment: would that sound be "Kerching!"?

Comment: StackOverflow is for programming questions -- user questions should go to http://android.stackexchange.com

Comment: yes man it is also a programming question suppose for alarm i want to play my own mp3 so how to set that mp3 for alarm ....

Answer (score 1):

put your mp3 in the raw folder. use media player to play that sound in the broadcast receiver.

Answer (score 0):

Try out [THIS](http://www.appbrain.com/app/alarm-klock/com.angrydoughnuts.android.alarmclock) little application it allows you to use your own MP3's or ring tones